# How do file operations work in C++ since they are different from Java?

Tags: java, c++, file, methods

I'm a Java developer, so when trying to operate on a file you instantiate an object of the class, File. The object, by default, will have methods such as `getAbsoluteFile()`.

In C++, however, according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/), you use a type called FILE which is defined within the stdio.h header file. Since it is not an object but a type, it will not have methods so how does one operate on it -- in particular, how does one rename a FILE?

What is the equivalent of having an object which has methods in C++ if it's different from Java (it seems different, judging from the File scenario)?

Comment: You are actually talking about C file functionality, not C++.

Comment: Unlike Java, neither C nor C++ have a notion of a "file system". Thus there is no such thing as file names, renaming, deleting, or listing directories in either language's standard library.

Comment: @KerrekSB C++ does have two functions, `remove` (to delete a file) and `rename` (to rename a file).  But that's about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FILE` is from the C standard library and is included in C++ for backwards compatibility. C doesn't provide support for OOP so it doesn't have methods at all. You operate on `FILE`s with free functions instead.

If you look at the sidebar on the site you linked you'll see a list of functions from the `cstdio` header. Most of the functions that have names starting with f take a `FILE*` as the first parameter. To rename files you can use [rename](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/); it doesn't take a `FILE*`, it takes two paths (as `char*`).

The more C++ way of doing file I/O is to use [streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing two different things.

In Java a [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is an object describing a thing in the filesystem and and to alter/add to the data in the file you have to create a stream from the file.

In C FILE is a handle to an open file and is used for changing the data in the file. In C++ you should really be using [IOStreams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io). C and C++ standards don't have the equivalent of the Java File the neaerest equivalent is the [Boost Filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) .

Answer (score 0):

You don't rename a FILE, you rename a file. There is a function called `rename` that renames a file. It doesn't operate on an object, since C++ inherited it from C which doesn't have objects. It's just a free function that takes the old name and the new name as parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
rename("oldFileName.txt", "newFileName.txt");
```

Comment: Does this method assume that the files are in the current working directory?

Comment: Not quite. If the path is a relative path, then it's relative to the current working directory. If it's an absolute path (begins with a `/`, or whatever your platform's rules are) then no. So you can do `rename("directory/file.txt", "/foo.txt");` That will rename the file "file.txt" in the directory "directory" in the current working directory to "foo.txt" in the root directory.